# How often do commercial flights go-around?

Tags: landing, go-around

I've seen many references here to a flight going around, and YouTube is filled with videos of it happening, but I don't recall ever having been on a commercial flight that had an aborted landing. It might have happened when I flew as a small child, but, having been really, *really* excited to fly, I think I'd have remembered that.

How often do commercial flights actually abort a landing and have to make another attempt?

I'm primarily curious about US statistics, but non-US would be interesting as well.

Comment: related question about the cost of a [go-around](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8766/how-much-does-go-around-cost)

Comment: A) Thanks, @pondlife - I was looking for "go-around", not "Abort". B) so **that's** how `Community♦` gets involved in closing a question.

Answer (score 8):

As [mentioned here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go-around#Safety):

> Go-arounds occur with an average rate of 1–3 per 1000 approaches.

Most of the videos on YouTube are of go-arounds because of weather. This is not a common scenario as many flights divert to other airports where weather is less severe.

Comment: Since I don't think I've flown that many times, that seems to be well within my statistical sample size for having missed it.

Comment: @FreeMan - Go-arounds and diverts are rarer for commercial flights than private. First because airlines use pilots with thousands of hours' experience flying complex aircraft under IFR, and second because the 5-10 minutes inherent in a go-around can send ripples through an entire airport's flight/gate schedule if it happens at the wrong time or the flight's already late (headwind, delayed T/O), so pilots are pressured by their companies to get it right the first time even in a crosswind.